# StartCopyFromBlob in Azure SDK 2.0 taking days?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a situation where I am copying lots of blobs from one storage container to another and some of the blobs have copied but a lot of them are still pending after two days since I initiated the copy. I am making this determination based on the fact that if I try to do anything with the destination blob I am getting the below error:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException : There is
>   currently a pending copy operation.   ----> System.Net.WebException :
>   The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.

Is there anything I can do about this? For example can I abort the copy after the fact?

Here is the copy code I am using to perform the copy.

```
try
{
    destinationBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(
       new Uri(sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + signature));
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(
       "Copying: {0}", destinationEndpoint.EndpointState.BlobName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var we = ex.InnerException as WebException;
    if (we != null && we.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(
           "conflict with blob copy for blob {0}", sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you already know that [Copy Blob operation is now asynchronous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx). Thus when you call `StartCopyFromBlob` operation on a blob, Blob Storage Service puts the copy operation in a queue. Since it's an async operation you wouldn't know when it will be processed. From what I understand, that the maximum time for that is 2 weeks <del>7 days</del> i.e. a copy operation can take a maximum of 2 weeks <del>7 days</del> and if it is not completed in 2 weeks <del>7 days</del>, it will be cancelled by the service.

Now coming to your questions:

> Is there anything i can do about this?

I don't think so. You can't change the queue priority.

> For example can i abort the copy after the fact?

Yes, you can. When you call [`StartCopyFromBlob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj717428.aspx), you get back a string which identifies the copy operation (it's called copy id). You could use this copy id and call [`AbortCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.abortcopy.aspx) operation on that blob. You could also get this copy id after the fact by fetching blob properties using [`FetchAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.fetchattributes.aspx) method. The property you would want to inspect is [`CopyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.copystate_members.aspx).

Comment: perfect. just what i needed to know. will use copy id to abort after the fact. thanks much!

Comment: one last question though, how do you change the queue priority in regards to the copy operation? I have searched the docs and cant seem to find any reference to this.

Comment: That was my bad! You can't really change the queue priority. So once a copy job is queued, you either wait for the job to finish or cancel that job using AbortCopy. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The article you linked too mentions a 2 week period for the copy to occur, instead of 7 days. `3.Currently there is no limit on the number of pending copy blobs that can be queued up for a storage account, but a pending copy blob operation can live in the system for at most 2 weeks. If longer than that, then the copy blob operation will be terminated. `

Comment: Thank you @julealgon. I was misinformed :). I have corrected my answer.